# mysql slow query log

Tags: mysql, logging, query

I am trying to write a script to parse the MySQL slow query log. I have seen 1 or 2 parser.
does anyone know how to extract the information from that log? I mean does anyone know the structure of the file so I can work with that and if anyone know a good parser for this log file?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldumpslow.html

Answer (score 0):

You may find this more helpful

mysqldumpslow -s t

For a quick summary Sorted with most Time consuming listed first.